# Why do I get random OSError (22) Invalid argument exceptions while receiving data from a python socket?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to receive some length of bytes from a python socket. Sometimes it works just fine without any error. But randomly I'm getting this error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Here is the code where the error is caused:

```
    try:
        #Just a protocol header
        header = socket.recv(self.HEADERSIZE)

        #Length of the content, sent by the client
        length = int.from_bytes(header[1:len(header)], byteorder='big')

        #line where the error is cause
        byte = socket.recv(length) 

        return header[0], byte
    except InterruptedError as e:
        e.with_traceback()
```

**header**: 5 bytes where the length of the content is given

This line is the important one:
**byte = socket.recv(length)**

Does anyone know why I get this random error?

Comment: Did you debug length ... print(length) ?

Comment: Yes. It seems like the socket is not reading the full length of data. So for example the length variable is 8192 but the socket just reads 7949. Then in the next packet the length variable becomes a huge number bc in the previous packet the packet was not read completely. How can I fix it that the socket always reads the given length of bytes?